# redirecting users after login django

Tags: django, python-3.x

By default after login django redirects the user to an accounts/profile page or if you edit the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL you can send the user to another page you specify in the settings.py. I want my users to, after logged in, not be able to go to the login page but instead be redirected to the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL automatically. Is there a way of doing it using the default login view? Any input is appreciated.

Comment: you can check `if request.user.is_authenticated` in your login view and redirect

Comment: You can check like comment above by using Middleware in django

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `redirect_authenticated_user` in `LoginView` to achieve that, [reference here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView).

You can use it by customize your own LoginView or simply just override the property on the fly in the `urlpatterns` like so:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='myapp/login.html', redirect_authenticated_user=True)),
]
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks it really does